# SO_LINGER option not causing close() to wait

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming

I wrote the following code in order to make an **echo server** (data I write to stdout moves from my PC to server and back to my PC). In the code **I set the SO_LINGER option** in the socket. So when I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> which caused client.cpp to send a FIN to server.cpp, the ***client.cpp's close() should wait for 10s for server.cpp's socket to send back a FIN***.

But what i found was that **client.cpp immediately finished execution and exited** after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> was pressed and even the **close() funcion didn't return -1** which it should have if the other side doesn't send FIN before the time mentioned in l_linger expires (**I am sure that the server didn't send a FIN or it must have been listed in tcpdump**.) The server side didn't send a FIN unless I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on its terminal. The tcpdump until I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on the server's terminal is shown in the screenshot:

[image]

The highlighted lines above are client's FIN.

**client.cpp:**

```
int main()
{
    int clifd;
    clifd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    sockaddr_in serv;
    bzero(&serv, sizeof(serv));
    serv.sin_family=AF_INET;
    serv.sin_port=htons(3345);
    inet_aton("127.0.0.1", &(serv.sin_addr));

    linger lin;
    unsigned int y=sizeof(lin);
    lin.l_onoff=1;
    lin.l_linger=10;
    setsockopt(clifd,SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER,(void*)(&lin), y);  

    connect(clifd, (sockaddr*)(&serv), sizeof(serv));
    int n,m;
    char data[100];
    char recvd[100];
    for(;;)
    {
        fgets(data, 100,stdin );
        n=strlen(data);
        cout<<"You have written "<<n<<endl;

        if(n>0)
        {
            while(n>0)
            {  
                m=write(clifd,data,n);
                n=n-m;
            }
        }

        n=read(clifd, recvd, 100);
        cout<<"Server echoed back "<<n<<endl; 

        if(n>0)
        {
            while(n>0)
            {
                m=fputs(data,stdout);  
                cout<<"m is"<<m<<endl; 
                fflush(stdout);
                n=n-m;
            }
            //cout<<data<<endl;
        }
    }
    int z=close(clifd);
    if(z==-1)
        cout<<"close returned -1 "<<endl; ***//this doesn't get printed***
}
```

**server.cpp:**

```
void reflect(int x)
{
    int n;
    int m;
    char data[100];
    cout<<"Entered reflect function"<<endl; 

    for(;;)
    {
        n=read(x,data, 100); 
        cout<<"Client sent "<<n<<endl; 

        if(n>0)
        {
            while(n>0)
            {
                m=write(x,data,n);
                n=n-m;
            }
            cout<<"Successfully echoed back to client"<<endl;  
        }
    }//end of for loop
}

int main()
{
    sockaddr_in serv;
    bzero(&serv, sizeof(serv));
    serv.sin_family=AF_INET;
    serv.sin_port=htons(3345);
    inet_aton("127.0.0.1", &(serv.sin_addr));

    int servfd=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    int x;
    x=bind(servfd, (sockaddr*)(&serv), sizeof(serv));

    cout<<"Bind returned"<<x<<endl; //this displays x as 0

    listen(servfd, 5);
    sockaddr cli;
    int connfd;
    pid_t id=-1;
    socklen_t siz=sizeof(cli);
    for(;;)
    {
        if((connfd=accept(servfd, &cli, &siz))>=0)
            id=fork();

        if(id==0)
            reflect(connfd);
        else 
            continue;
    }
}
```

Why is client's close() not waiting?

Comment: Why do you assume `Ctrl+C` won't just terminate your application (and hence not give it the opportunity to see the socket being closed)?  You don't catch `SIGINT` in your client app, and the `FIN` that you see is likely due to the socket being forcefully closed by your application "going away".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, the client.cpp 's close() should wait for 10s for server.cpp 's socket to send back a FIN.

That's not correct. It should wait for all the outgoing data and the outgoing FIN to be sent, or for the timer to expire. There is no statement anywhere that entitles you to expect it to wait for an incoming FIN.

Answer (score 5):

> Why is client's close() not waiting?

You are not calling `close()` in your client. The `for` loop that immediately precedes your `close()` call never exits, therefore the `close()` can never occur.

Typing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> in your console causes the program to exit immediately, without performing any of the remaining actions.

Since `close()` is never invoked, the rest of your question (should `close()` wait? should I use `closesocket()`? etc) is moot.

If you do want to be able to exit the `for(;;)` loop, try something like this:

```
for(;;)
{
  if(fgets(data, 100,stdin ) == NULL)
    break;
  ... rest of loop goes here ...
```

Then, when you run your client program, do not terminate it with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, but rather type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> as the only character on the line.

Comment: You could show the OP how to make this close call happen, using `signal.h`, and some state flags.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on an answer above, if you want to get your `close()` function called, make these relatively simple changes to your client:

```
#include <signal.h>

volatile bool stop_now = false;

// This function will be called when SIGINT (Ctrl+C)
// is received, and will set this global flag that
// will terminate your loop below.
void app_stopped(int sig)
{
    stop_now = true;
}


int main()
{
   // setup to catch Ctrl+C
   signal(SIGINT, app_stopped);

   ...

   // for(;;)
   // becomes:
   while(!stop_now)
   {
      ...
   }
   ...
}
```

Now, when you send a SIGINT (via `Ctrl+C` or via `kill -s INT`) your program will stop gracefully and your `close()` function will be called.  You can start troubleshooting from there.

Comment: +1, but you probably want the `bool stop_now` to be `volatile bool stop_now`?

Answer (score 2):

From the [`linger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms739165%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) reference on MSDN (if you don't trust msdn, you can find the same information [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Socket_002dLevel-Options.html#Socket_002dLevel-Options))

> The linger structure maintains information about a specific socket that specifies how that socket should behave when data is queued to be sent and the closesocket function is called on the socket.

So it will wait until all data has been sent, not until a FIN has been received.